# How do I apply the circle animation to the cell?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a play button in each cell, and when it is clicked I want the circle animation will initiate and circle the circumference of the button. I have a separate swift file for the animation, but I do not know how to implement that to the cell. How would I do that? Below is the code for the button in the cell.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 


    cell.textLabel?.text = ret[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Lombok", size: 22)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor =  UIColorFromRGB("4A90E2")

    let playButton : UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
    playButton.tag = indexPath.row
    let imageret = "playbutton"
    playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: imageret), forState: .Normal)
    playButton.frame = CGRectMake(230, 20, 100, 100)
    playButton.addTarget(self,action: "playit:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    for view: UIView in cell.contentView.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }


    cell.contentView.addSubview(playButton)

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    return cell
}

 func playit(sender: UIButton!){


}
```

Below is the code to the circle animation.

```
import UIKit
class Shape: UIView {

    /*
    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */
    var circleLayer: CAShapeLayer!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        // Use UIBezierPath as an easy way to create the CGPath for the layer.
        // The path should be the entire circle.
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2.0, y: frame.size.height / 2.0), radius: (frame.size.width - 10)/2, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0), clockwise: true)

        // Setup the CAShapeLayer with the path, colors, and line width
        circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        circleLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath
        circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        circleLayer.lineWidth = 5.0;

        // Don't draw the circle initially
        circleLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0

        // Add the circleLayer to the view's layer's sublayers
        layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func animateCircle(duration: NSTimeInterval) {
        // We want to animate the strokeEnd property of the circleLayer
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

        // Set the animation duration appropriately
        animation.duration = duration

        // Animate from 0 (no circle) to 1 (full circle)
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = 1

        // Do a linear animation (i.e. the speed of the animation stays the same)
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)

        // Set the circleLayer's strokeEnd property to 1.0 now so that it's the
        // right value when the animation ends.
        circleLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0

        // Do the actual animation
        circleLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "animateCircle")
    }

    func addCircleView() {
        let diceRoll = CGFloat(Int(arc4random_uniform(7))*50)
        var circleWidth = CGFloat(200)
        var circleHeight = circleWidth

        // Create a new CircleView
        var circleView = Shape(frame: CGRectMake(diceRoll, 0, circleWidth, circleHeight))

        self.addSubview(circleView)

        // Animate the drawing of the circle over the course of 1 second
        circleView.animateCircle(1.0)
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're off to a good start. You need to rewrite your cellForRowAtIndexPath method so it only adds the button if you are creating a new cell (if dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns nil.)

Then you need to add code in your button's IBAction (`playIt') that invokes your animation.

However, your animation code can't use a global `circleLayer` property. You need a way to fetch the shape layer from the button. You could create a custom subclass of UIButton that has a shape layer property, or you could loop through sender's sublayers in the IBAction, looking for a shape layer.

Comment: How would I create a custom subclass of the UIButton? is it just a class within the button function?

Comment: I created a subclass of the UIButton, but how do I connect it to the button in the cell?

Comment: In your code that populates your cell create one of your custom buttons rather than a UIButton. In the IBAction for the button add code to verify that the button is of the correct class, then cast it to your custom type, fetch the shape layer from the button subclass's property and animate it.

Comment: `let playButton : UIButton = ShapLayer(type: UIButtonType.Custom)`. ShapeLayer is the name of the subclass

Comment: `ShapLayer` is a dreadful name for a button. It's not a layer, it's a button. Then you're assigning it to a variable of type UIButton. Make playButton be a variable of your custom button class. And you probably need to call a custom initializer that sets up the shape layer property. (Or at least override the existing initializer in your custom class.)